# AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION: pros and cons

Tags: oracle, transactions

Can be autonomous transactions dangerous? If yes, in which situations? When autonomous transactions are necessary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, autonomous transactions can be dangerous.

Consider the situation where you have your main transaction. It has inserted/updated/deleted rows. If you then, within that, set up an autonomous transaction then either

(1) It will not query any data at all. This is the 'safe' situation. It can be useful to log information independently of the primary transaction so that it can be committed without impacting the primary transaction (which can be useful for logging error information when you expect the primary transaction to be rolled back).

(2) It will only query data that has not been updated by the primary transaction. This is safe, but superfluous. There is no point to the autonomous transaction.

(3). It will query data that has been updated by the primary transaction. This smacks of a poorly thought through design, since you've overwritten something and then need to go back to see what it was before you overwrote it. Sometimes people think that an autonomous transaction will still see the uncommitted changes of the primary transaction, and it won't. It reads the currently committed state of the database, plus any changes made within the autonomous transaction. Some people (often trying autonomous transactions in response to mutating trigger errors) don't care what state the data is in when they try to read it and these people simply shouldn't be allowed access to a database.

(4). It will try to update/delete data that hasn't been updated by the primary transaction. Again, this smacks of poor design. These changes are going to get committed (or rolled back) whether or not the primary transaction succeeds or fails. Worse you risk issue (5) since it is hard to determine, within an autonomous transaction, whether the data has been updated by the primary transaction.

(5). You try to update/delete data that has already been updated by the primary transaction, in which case it will deadlock and end up in an ugly mess.

Comment: +1 The only cast-iron use case for Autonmous Transactions is logging/auditing. Everything else is iffy or downright dangerous.

Answer (score 11):

**Can be autonomous transactions dangerous?**

Yes.

**If yes, in which situations?**

When they're misused. For example, when used to make changes to data which should have been rolled back if the rest of the parent transaction is rolled back. Misusing them can cause data corruption because some portions of a change are committed, while others are not.

**When are autonomous transactions necessary?**

They are necessary when the effects of one transaction must survive, regardless of whether the parent transaction is committed or rolled back. A good example is a procedure which logs the progress and activity of a process to a database table.

Answer (score 0):

**When are autonomous transactions necessary?**

Check my question: [How can LOCK survive COMMIT or how can changes to LOCKed table be propagated to another session without COMMIT and losing LOCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872740/how-can-lock-survive-commit-or-how-can-changes-to-locked-table-be-propagated-to/52873447#52873447)

We ingest business configurations sequentially and should forbid parallel processing.

I use lock to table with configurations and update other tables accordingly. I commit  each batched updates to other tables as we can't afford to keep transaction on all records - probability of collision would be near 0.99.

Each failure because of concurrent access is persisted to log for later update attempt.