# How can LOCK survive COMMIT or how can changes to LOCKed table be propagated to another session without COMMIT and losing LOCK

Tags: oracle, transactions

I want `LOCK TABLE` for longer than to the next `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK`.

For instance, I locked table, corrected its state and want subsequently update other tables but I don't want to keep locks for other tables for too long and expect to do a lot of `COMMIT`.

So I will do `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` for other tables but still want to prevent any modification to base table.

It looks like I need to open two sessions to DB. Keep `LOCK TABLE` in one and process tables in another. But I don't understand how can I propagate changes to base table without closing LOCK by `COMMIT` so they will be visible in another session.

Comment: You can do the subsequent changes in `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`s or work with `SAVEPOINT`s... Look here for a good start: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG

Comment: The AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION pragma changes the way a subprogram works within a transaction. A subprogram marked with this pragma can do SQL operations and commit or roll back those operations, without committing or rolling back the data in the main transaction.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`

```
drop table EX_EMPLOYEE
/
drop table EX_EMPLOYEE1
/
create table EX_EMPLOYEE
(id number(4) null)
/
create table EX_EMPLOYEE1
(id number(4) null)
/
insert into EX_EMPLOYEE (id) values(1);
/
insert into EX_EMPLOYEE1 (id) values(1);
/
commit
/
create or replace procedure P_TEST
as
  begin
  DELETE FROM EX_EMPLOYEE WHERE ID =1;
  P_TEST1();

end;
/

create or replace procedure P_TEST1
as
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
    DELETE FROM EX_EMPLOYEE1 WHERE ID =1;
commit;
end;
/
```

then execute the procedure

```
begin
P_TEST();
end;
/
```

when finishes select on the 2 tables, youll notice the first table still contains the row, however the second the row is deleted.

```
select * from ex_employee where id =1;
select * from ex_employee1 where id =1;
```

You can also check from the database that the table is still locked:

```
SELECT * FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT L
INNER JOIN USER_OBJECTS  U ON(L.OBJECT_ID=U.OBJECT_ID);
```

Don't forget after this test to commit or rollback to release the lock.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to write this up! I intentionally need to keep one table in consistent state while other should be processed without disturbing main business logic. I'll mark failures and process them later, it is probable that in another time frame those records would be free from transactions and I succeed.